# How can I change a header's bottom border color depending on the scroll location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress website and am wondering why my jQuery code isn't working. My goal is to have the bottom border of the main header change relative to the document's scroll location, specifically when certain anchor tags are in view.

Here's the website:

http://dev.celebrate-life.info

And here's the live mockup which features the bottom border color change I'm trying to emulate:

http://clfmockup3.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Here's the default CSS:

```
.x-navbar,
.x-navbar-fixed-top {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f0b33e;
}
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using to alter the above CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}

var myelement = $('#joinus'); // the element to act on if viewable
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
      $(".x-navbar, .x-navbar-fixed-top").css({
        'border-bottom': '3px solid #f0b33e',
      }); // change color of header bottom border
    } else {
        // do something when element is not viewable
    }
});
```

});

I'm beginning to wonder if this is even a good method of achieving the desired result, but I can't even get the bottom border to change so I can see how it looks/works in a live environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can store the color in each section using data-attributes and when the section is scrolled into view get its data-color and apply to the border

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any idea why this question was voted down? I want to make sure I'm abiding the rules, and I'm new so any feedback about how I asked the question would be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Am not sure why this was downvoted. Probably the person felt you haven't tried anything and got the code from the site you have mentioned.

Comment: Bummer. That's definitely not the case as the mockup site is using a totally different (and mysterious to me) technique. Either way, thanks for weighing in.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here once, here is nice example https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/